# For a measurable cardinal $κ$, show that $cf(γ)≠κ$ implies $j_U(γ)=\sup\{j_U(δ):δ<γ\}$ ($U$ $κ$-complete ultrafilter, $j_U$ associated embedding)

Tags: set-theory, cardinals, large-cardinals

For :

- $κ$ a measurable cardinal,
- $U$ a $κ$-complete ultrafilter over $κ$
- $j_U$ the elementary embedding of $V$ into the ultrapower of $V$ to $U$

How to show that :  If $\operatorname{cf}(γ)≠κ$ Then $j_U(γ)= \sup \{j_U(δ)\mid δ<γ\}$ ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Please use the [mathJax basic tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) and enhance your question.

Comment: Could you explain what have you tried for?

Comment: for the case cf(γ)<κ, I think of using the κ-completeness of the ultrafilter but I don't know for the case cf(γ)>κ.. maybe just a cofinality argument ? I am not sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us divide the cases. Let $\langle \gamma_\zeta\mid \zeta<\mu\rangle$ be a cofinal sequence converging to $\gamma$. (Here $\mu=\operatorname{cf}\gamma$.)

- $\operatorname{cf}\gamma<\kappa$: Let $[f]_U<j_U(\gamma)$. Without loss of generality we may assume that $f(\xi)<\gamma$ for all $\xi<\kappa$. (Why?) For each $\xi$, choose $\eta_\xi<\mu$ such that $f(\xi)<\gamma_{\eta_\xi}$. Then there is $\delta<\mu$ such that $\{\xi<\kappa\mid \eta_\xi=\delta\}\in U$. Can you see how to proceed from there?
- $\operatorname{cf}\gamma>\kappa$: Let $[f]_U<j_U(\gamma)$ again. Still, we may assume that $f(\xi)<\gamma$ for all $\xi<\kappa$. Since $\kappa<\mu$, $\delta:=\sup_{\xi<\kappa}f(\xi)<\gamma$. Then completing the proof is easy, so I will leave it to you.

Comment: Thank you but I don't see how to finish the first proof..

Comment: @Cantor'sturtle Could you point out where you are stuck in?

Comment: Well I think that with the κ-completeness we can show that f converges to  but then why does it show (γ)=sup{(δ)∣δ<γ} ?

Comment: @Cantor'sturtle No, what we can show from the previous argument is that for each $[f]_U<j_U(\gamma)$ we can find $\delta<\mu$ such that $[f]_U<j_U(\gamma_\delta)$.

Comment: ok yes I got this